# Unable to respond to script asking question inside emacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I am trying to adopt *spacemacs* for elixir development. As a first step, I have managed to enable *elixir-mode*, which means that I can run MIX (`C-c a x`). When I run MIX I want to use the `phx.new` option to create a new Phoenix project. Unfortunately, one of the first things this does is to ask me whether I want to install dependencies (which is something I **do** want to do). However, there does not seem to be a way of entering the 'Y' response inside the Emacs buffer that is showing the MIX command being executed. I have tried toggling read-only mode, but with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try evaluating this:

```
(defun my-send-y ()
  (interactive)
  (process-send-string (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) "y\n"))
```

And then hit `M-x my-send-y` to send `y` to the process in the current buffer.

Comment: thanks for the info. Unfortunately, I am a total emacs newbie (sorry) - where should I add this code? Note also, I do not have the option of modifying the MIX script, since this is part of the elixir distro.

Comment: Pls ignore - I'll add it to my ~/.emacs file